# Passing dictionary and list values dynmically to a json payload

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a table ID as key and table name as value and another list that has a list of dicts of that corresponds to table refresh policies. I am trying to dynamically pass dictionary values and list elements to a JSON blob and then pass that to an API post request but looks like I'm sending duplicate requests to the post request.

*P.S: This is just sample data that looks like original data.*

```
d = {101: bh, 
     102: cy,
     103: ui,
     104: act}

l = [{'refresh_method': 'FULL'},
     {'refresh_method': 'FULL'},
     {'refresh_method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refresh_field': 'updated_at'},
     {'refresh_method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refresh_field': 'updated_at'}]


for key, value in d.items():
    for a in l:
        payload = {
        "entityType": "dataset",
        "id":  key,
        "path":  value,
        "type": "PHYSICAL_DATASET",
        "accelerationRefreshPolicy": {
            "method": a['refresh_method'],    
            "refreshField": a['refresh_field'],
            "neverRefresh": True,
            "neverExpire": True,
        },
     }
    resp = requests.requests('POST', url, json=payload)
```

When I print the payload I don't see the values from the second loop. Is it because of two loops? Is there a better way to do it?

```
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 101, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'bh'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 102, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'cy'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 103, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'ui'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 104, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'act'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
```

Expected result:

```
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 101, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'bh'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'FULL', 'refreshField':'', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 102, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'cy'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'FULL', 'refreshField': '', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 103, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'ui'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
{'entityType': 'dataset', 'id': 104, 'path': ['db', 'public', 'act'], 'type': 'PHYSICAL_DATASET', 'accelerationRefreshPolicy': {'method': 'INCREMENTAL', 'refreshField': 'updated_at', 'neverRefresh': True, 'neverExpire': True}}
```

Really appreciate it if I can get some help here.

Comment: Your `requests.requests()` call is outside of the loop. So it's just sending the last payload.

Comment: My bad. It is actually inside the loop

Comment: But it's not inside the inner loop. So it only shows the last value of `a`.

Comment: Why are you expecting only 4 results? You have 16 different values of `payload` from all the combinations of `d` and `l`.

Comment: If you want to loop in parallel, use `for (key, value), a in zip(d.items(), l)`

Comment: If I put the resp inside the second loop it gives me 16 and I don't want that. What I want is to run in parallel

Comment: That worked. Thank you @Barmar!!